# Why is there a difference of one in down function of Z notation for the solution to 8 Queen problem?

Tags: formal-verification, formal-methods, z-notation

I was reading the book titled "The Way of Z: Practical Programming with Formal Methods by Jonathan Jacky" and in chapter 18 (8 Queen problem), the author provided a Z notation based formal solution to the famous 8 queen problem.
He tried to solve the diagonal part by connecting it to a straight line equation. 
The variables used in the solutions are:

[image: variables]

Then the straight-line equations to solve the diagonal part are:
[image: lineEquation]
where file represents a row here and rank represents a column.
The Image that is provided to help us understand the diagonals is:
[image: diagonalImage]

The solution works as follows:
The file(row) number 1 is highlighted in blue.
The rank(column) 1 is highlighted in red.
The solution goes from downside to up and from left to right.

I want to calculate the up and down function values for the square at file(row)=4 and rank(column)=6 (highlighted in yellow).

So,

up = rank - file = 6 - 4 = 2

down = rank + file = 6 + 4 = 10

as can be seen in the image above, the up diagonal line does cut the left edge for y-intercept at point 2. But the down diagonal line cuts the y-intercept at point 9 (instead of 10). There is a difference of 1. And this difference is for all square. 
I want to know what piece am I missing in this case? Why is there always a difference in the case of the down arrow (and not in the case of the up arrow)?

I am also attaching the full Z notation based solution for reference here:
[image: fullSolution]

Answer (score 1):

The projection depicted in the picture and the one in the text are different, but that doesn't appear to truly matter: the only properties that needs to be maintained are that **1.** the `up()/down()` projection of two Queens on the same diagonal is the same **2.** the `up()/down()` projection of two Queens on a different diagonal is different.

The excerpt of the book that you placed in the question does not appear to be that much clear about this, but *(as far as I can tell)* the `up()` (resp. `down()`) projection of a Queen should only be compared with the `up()` (resp. `down()`) projections of other Queens in order to determine whether they sit on the same diagonal. Otherwise, the validity of such comparison would be trivially falsifiable, **e.g.**
given a `q1 := Queen(1, 1)` and `q2 := Queen(6, 4)`, it is easy to see that `down(q1) == up(q2)` but `q1, q2` don't  attack each other.